# How to run own object detector using dlib library on android?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

Using windows 10.
I am trying to run my own object detector model that trained using dlib library and its working on python perfectly.

```
`detector = dlib.simple_object_detector("mobiledatasetv2/detector.dat")
 image = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
 image = imutils.resize(image, width=500)
 rects = detector(image)
 for k, d in enumerate(rects):
 print("Detection {}: Left: {} Top: {} Right: {} Bottom: {}".format(k, 
 d.left(), d.top(), d.right(), d.bottom()))`
```

After that I try to run on android so I download sample project from here "https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android-app" to check how to run dlib on android. It seems that android uses shared object ".so" file, so I try to build my model's shared object file. I take help from here "https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android" to build it.

I use this command to build ".so" file
    `python build.py --jobs 1 --android_project 
C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\sources\third_party\vulkan\src\build-android\jniLibs --debug`

After resolving NDK, toolchain and path issues

I stuck on this issue

> C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/Android.mk:c++_static:
>   LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME must not contain a file extension
>   C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/build-static-library.mk:26:
>   *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop. Build Error

I debug and found that LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME file is: libc++_static.a which is present in

> AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\libs\armeabi v7a this folder.

If I remove libc++_static.a file extention and make it like libc++_static only then it give this error

> C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:25:
>   *** Android NDK:  Assertion failure: LOCAL_PREBUILT_SUFFIX is not defined    .  Stop. Build Error

If I explicetly set
LOCAL_PREBUILT_SUFFIX := .a 
then error comes

> ERROR:C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/Android.mk:c++_static:
>   LOCAL_SRC_FILES should point to a file ending with ".a" Android NDK:
>   The following file is unsupported: libs/armeabi-v7a/libc++_static
>   C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:41:
>   *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop. Build Error

Comment: This is not Java, this looks like Python code.

Comment: Yes its python code which is working for me but if I try to build my own .so file for my android application it gives above errors.